# Is there any native api in node to process request with its contentType set to multipart/form-data?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Or any popular lib?
I'm not saying that I need to process request in the front end. I'm working on a backend demo node project. And I want to take out data from request that send from the front end and the contentType of the request's header is 'multipart/form-data'.
I'm learning node, and I've encountered a problem that the document of node is not as detailed as java's, because there's no description on some callbacks and its params. Or I'm using the document in a wrong way?
Any help is appreciated, thanks to all you guys.
I'm also a new English learner, sorry for my words.

Comment: `res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')` did you try setting this ?

Comment: @KunalMukherjee Thanks. But I mean process in the back-end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use **body-parser**

```
var express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

var app = express()

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

Comment: thank you. And is there any lib that doesn't depend on express. sorry, my english is not good, so I'm not sure 'depend on' is right or not. I mean is there any lib that has no dependencies on any other lib?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to request something the most popular library is 'axios' but you can use the http lib already included in node:

https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v8.x/api/http.html

If you want to handle http request you can use popular library like express with body-parse.

For the next time if you want to find something with node you can search on google like this.

'Node handle form urlencoded request ' or
'Node node request url encoded'

Comment: thanks for your help. I know axios, this question is on the back-end node.  Is there any lib that has no dependency on express or koa or any other lib.